# Why is my way of solving $5^{4x+1} = 7^{x+2}$ invalid?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I know I could just express

$$5^{4x+1} = 7^{x+2}$$

as $(4x+1)\log 5 = (x+2)\log 7$ but I wanted to try something off the cuff. Here's what my thought process was.

$$7^\alpha = 5$$

$$\alpha = \frac{\log 5}{\log 7}$$

Since both bases can be expressed as $5$, we can equate their exponents.

$$\alpha x + 2\alpha = 4x+1$$

$$x\ (4 - \alpha) = 1 - 2\alpha$$

$$x = \frac {1-2\alpha}{4-\alpha}$$

$$x = \frac{1 - 2\frac{\log 5}{\log 7}}{4 - \frac{\log 5}{\log 7}}$$

Approximating $\frac{\log 5}{\log 7}$ as about $0.827$, $x$ is roughly:

$$x = 0.478$$

However, this is not true. What did I do wrong, if my logic is sound?

Comment: You want $\alpha(4x+1)=x+2$.

Comment: @Arthur That's right Arthur. Let me edit it for clarity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, it should be $$(7^\alpha)^{4x+1}=7^{x+2}\\\alpha(4x+1)=x+2$$Then you dropped a sign going from $$\alpha x + 2\alpha = 4x+1$$ to $$x\ (4 - \alpha) = 1 - 2\alpha$$.  The right side should be $2 \alpha -1$

Comment: Oh, you're right. Thank you!